# Using If statement in Linq to SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have this query:

```
Dim Query = From E In db.Employee Select E
```

Now inside the Employee table there is a boolean field Called "isActive".

if the IsActive value equals to True i want the result to show that IsActive equals to "Active" and the same for IsActive=false to show InActive when binding to a gridview"

Comment: I clearly missed the point of your question. Your comment was " if the IsActive value equals to True i want the result to show that IsActive equals to "Active" and the same for IsActive=false to show InActive when binding to a gridview". Can you add this information into your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to display "Active" or "Inactive" in your gridview rather than "True" or "False" in the IsActive-column?

If so, I can see two different approaches.

**Variant 1:**

You could select a new anonymous type and bind to the gridview (forgive me, I don't know the VB syntax but this is how it would be done in C#):

```
Dim Query = From E In db.Employee Select New With _
{ _
    .Id = E.Id, _
    .Name = E.Name, _
    .IsActive = E.IsActive ? "Active" : "Inactive" _
    ' ... all employee fields except IsActive, '
}
```

And then you just databind as usual.

**Variant 2:**

You let the gridview be a little smarter than just bind to the IsActive property. I.e., the gridview would do the `IsActive ? "Active" : "Inactive"` part.

For instance, you probably have something like this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="IsActive" HeaderText="IsActive" />
```

You can change this to a template field instead:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IsActive">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# GetIsActiveText((bool)Eval("IsActive")) %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In the code-behind file, you add a method GetIsActiveText() that return the correct string based on the boolean true/false value.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you are trying to achieve. You need something like this:

```
Dim Query = From e In db.Employee 
      select
      new
      {
       ID = e.ID,
       ActiveStr = e.IsActive?"Active":"Inactive"
      };
```

Please replace the "ID" field with whatever other fields you may wish to show in the query, separated by commas.

Answer (score 1):

```
ActiveStr = e.IsActive?"Active":"Inactive"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignore everyone recommending the condition ? trueBit : falseBit syntax as that is C# only. For VB, use the Ternary If (not IIF):

```
Dim query = From e In db.Employee  
            Select e.ID, 
                   ActiveStr = If(e.IsActive,"Active","Inactive")
```